# PHP login system?

Tags: java, php, java-me

What is the best way to make a user-login system using PHP?

I want to use the same login system to be called by another languages, also like

- [MIDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Information_Device_Profile)
- iPhone
- Java
- Desktop
- Flex

I don't want to use cookies.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I don't understand what you're asking, and you don't seem to be using any punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to use cookies

This drastically limits the possibilities you have. Now you can't go around URL-rewriting to append the session identifier to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a basic website login system, try this.

Login form:

```
<form id="login-form" class="loginform" action='include/login.inc.php' method='POST'>
                        <input  id="login-email" type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email'>
                        <input  id="login-pwd" type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password'>

                </form>
```

And then add the php code.

Login.inc.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../dbh.php';

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email= ? ";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result   = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if(password_verify($pwd, $row['pwd'])) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];   
    $userID = $row['id'];

    header("Location: ../profile.php?id=$userID");
    exit();
} else {
   header("Location: ../login-error-page.php");
   exit();
} 

?>
```