# Syntax on how can I show the login system first when I type the folder name in localhost

Tags: php, xampp

I don't know what the syntax is? What I want to happen is that when I type localhost/farm-e-mart the first file that should show the login system. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP login system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828571/php-login-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly if your web app permit user authentication, do this.

On the page, you don't want unauthenticated user to have access to, add this code at the top of the code script e.g profile.php

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION){
   header("location:login.php");
}
```

Then, on the login page add this code snippet.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION){
header("location:profile.php");
}
```

Comment: I hope this points you to the direction you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

check for cookies/session if the user is not logged in then redirect to login page.

if logging in is not compulsory but you want to make sure that user sees login page then create a session that gets initiated in login page. and check in other page if the session is there or not and then redirect

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).